# The plugin '[path]/APlugin.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (4.8.2) [debug]

Tags: qt, plugins

I am trying to compile a Qt Library Project to use its DLL as a plugin of my Main Application.
I've come across this particular error and I cannot seem to get past it, no matter what I try.

I believe cluttering the question with code tags is pointless when I can just provide you with the "working issue" (for lack of better wording).

[This is a link to both projects. The main application AND the plugin I am currently testing on.](http://www.mediafire.com/?f7afqcgj3v6x5fz)
(please remember to modify the path in the Application project of the dll. I am using absolute path, which will most likely never be the same one you will use. I used absolute paths to make sure the problem was unrelated to finding the file itself)

So far I've checked:

- My Qt version is, indeed, 4.8.2. Built with VS2010 Command Prompt.
- As far as I understood the documentation, my code (particularly the APlugin project) follows the documentation instructions word by word. There's some space for human error, but I believe I got it right. [as specified here(The Lower-Level API: Extending Qt Applications)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/plugins-howto.html)
- I am able to generate other QPluginLoader::errorString() errors (for example, using an invalid path to the .dll file will return a "file not found" error). Thus diminishing the margin of error in its use.

As of today, Google results are, at best, cryptic and/or do not apply to my current context of development (I am on VS2010, Win7 N Ultimate, Qt 4.8.2)

I believe it's better that I provided projects where the issue is reproducible, instead of just cluttering the question with code, but if you think I still should copy-paste my code, let me know and I will provide it explicitely in the question.

The only thing I am able to provide so far is that, albet I don't use a .pro file, I shouldn't need it, because my application will be windows exclusive, and the vcproj file already contains that data.

Comment: Have you tried compiling in Release mode, just as a test?

Comment: Yes, I tried both on release and debug (And possible combinations). The only differences is that, if the APlugin.dll file is in release mode, the errorString() message changes from _The plugin '[path]/APlugin.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (4.8.2) **[debug]**_ to _The plugin '[path]/APlugin.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (4.8.2) **[release]**_